# What query language is most common for e-journal searches?

Tags: literature-search, online-publication

I need to teach a quick lesson on e-journal searching, e.g. to search for one item, excluding certain terms, or another item.

What is the most common query language that students will most likely encounter?

Comment: I've seen conflicting uses of AND and OR a lot. The AND keyword should be an intersection, but at my campus it is a union. So, tl;dr, ymmv.

Answer (score 6):

**Academic databases are built for people who have no idea what a 'query language' is.** I agree that the world would be a much better place if everyone knew a little bit of SQL, but it's not like that.

The only exception that I know is [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/), an academic database specialized to mathematics which includes a sort of text-based [query language](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/MIRROR/zmath/en/search/).

Every other academic database that I have worked with uses **custom-made input masks** where you can select manually fields to search on and logical operators; they look like [this example](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/MIRROR/zmath/en/advanced/), again from Zentralblatt.